# Update column value while binding in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'd like to update the values of column `Action` based on the value of the column `Status` which is Boolean. If `Status` is `True` then value in `Action` must update to `Deactivate`. When I run, the Action field doesn't updates. I think there is an error in codebehind.

Here is the codebehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            string value = e.Row.Cells[4].Text;

            TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("TextBox2");
            if (value == "True")
            {
                TextBox2.Text = "Take";
            }
            else if (value == "False")
            {
                TextBox2.Text = "Available";
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"       AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
AllowSorting="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">       
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ShopNumber" HeaderText="ShopNumber"     ItemStyle-Width="80" SortExpression="ShopNumber" >
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="ShopName" HeaderText="ShopName" ItemStyle-Width="80" SortExpression="ShopName" >
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address" ItemStyle-Width="80"SortExpression="Address" >
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:BoundField DataField="Website" HeaderText="Website" ItemStyle-Width="80" SortExpression="Website" >
</asp:BoundField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>            </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Status") %>'>   </asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemStyle Width="80px" />
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Action") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Action") %>'> </asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: So what issue you are facing? You forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple issues. First, you are trying to update the "Status" column by setting the text of `TextBox2`. In your question, you wanted to update the "Action" column.

Your second issue is that you are trying to update the TextBox in the `EditItemTemplate` of the column. On first run of the GridView, this template will not be shown. It will only be shown when the GridView is put into edit mode. What this means is that `TextBox2` shouldn't even be found.

What you need to do is first use the the correct column, whichever that may be. If that truly is the "Action" column, first try setting the `Label1` text value. If your GridView is in edit mode, set the `TextBox1` text value instead.

You also have two `EditItemTemplate` in your "Action" column. You probably don't want that and that may be causing an error.